# Browser page doesn't load when I open it with React using VSC

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to practice on it using VSC, but I ran into a problem. Before trying VSC, I practiced React a little bit at CodeSandbox.io, which worked perfectly, but when I try to implement the exact same code that worked in CodeSandbox on VSC, the page just doesn't load, more specifically, it loads, but this is what the page shows : [Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gckqf.png)

I have followed the React installing tutorial and everything, here's my code as well : Index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/src/index.js"></script>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello WORLD</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is VSC, ...Visual Studio Code (VScode)? It seems possibly important/relevant to your issue. What/how are you running your app locally?

Comment: Could you please share your package.json, have you run npm install and npm start commands?

Comment: Sorry, by VSC I meant, Visual Code Studio, made a typo. I will add the json file in a second. thanks

Comment: have run the commands? `npm install` and `npm start` ?

Comment: Yea I did in the Hyper Terminal, "npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
" I did this exact thing

Comment: try `pkill -9 node` and then open your project folder in terminal (CMD) and type `npm start`

Comment: Nevermind, Installing npm worked, thank you sir <3